# Parse nested dictionary python and remove complete hierarchy if all its leaf node is empty

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
c_dict = {'a': {'b': {'c': [1], 'd': [{'e': {'val': [1]}}, {'e': {'val': []}}]}}}
def clean_dict(d):
    for key, val in d.items():
        if isinstance(val, list):  # CAT -> This "if" handles list of dicts
            for i in val:
                if isinstance(i, dict):
                    val = clean_dict(i)
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            val = clean_dict(val)
        if val is None or val == {} or val == []:
            del d[key]
    return d
print clean_dict(c_dict)
```

The output is:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': [1]}}}
```

But the expected output is:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': [1], 'd':[{'e':{'val':[1]}}]}}}
```

As inside the list, there is a dict whose leaf node is not empty.
Please let me know what is missing here.

Comment: What output should be for `{'a': {'b': 1, 'c': []}}`

Comment: @Germn, {'a': {'b': 1}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clean_dict` function should create a new dictionary instead of modify in place the received dict. `val == {} or val == []` could be replaced by `len(val) == 0`

```
c_dict = {'a': {'b': {'c': [1], 'd': [{'e': {'val': [1]}}, {'e': {'val': []}}]}}}
def clean_dict(d):
    ret = {k: v for k, v in d.items()}
    for key, val in d.items():
    if isinstance(val, list):  # CAT -> This "if" handles list of dicts
        for i in val:
            if isinstance(i, dict):
                val = clean_dict(i)
        ret[key] = val
    elif isinstance(val, dict):
        val = clean_dict(val)
        ret[key] = val
    elif val is None or len(val) == 0:
        pass
    return ret
print clean_dict(c_dict)
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': [1], 'd': {'e': {'val': []}}}}}
```

But that's not the expected answer. Problem here is that lists are not properly handled. Let's encapsulate that in a dedicated function:

```
c_dict = {'a': {'b': {'c': [1], 'd': [{'e': {'val': [1]}}, {'e': {'val': []}}]}}}


def clean_dict(d):
    ret = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
    if isinstance(val, list):  # CAT -> This "if" handles list of dicts
        val = clean_list(val)
        if len(val) > 0:
            ret[key] = val
    elif isinstance(val, dict):
        val = clean_dict(val)
        if len(val) > 0:
            ret[key] = val
    return ret


def clean_list(l):
    ret = []
    for elem in l:
    try:
        iter(elem)  # raise TypeError if not iterable
        if isinstance(elem, dict):
            elem = clean_dict(elem)
            if len(elem) > 0:
                ret.append(elem)
        elif isinstance(elem, list):
            elem = clean_list(elem)
            if len(elem) > 0:
                ret.append(elem)
        else:
            ret.append(elem)
    except TypeError:  # elem is not an iterable
        ret.append(elem)
    return ret


print clean_dict(c_dict)
```

Which ouputs:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': [1], 'd': [{'e': {'val': [1]}}]}}}
```